# How to sum up item types within the same invoice to find percentages in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

Within an invoice, there are multiple items including a discount item.  How would I find the % discount for the entire invoice, then use that to calculate the adjusted dollars for each item?

I can find the percentages for each invoice using summarize and sumx, but i cant get it to the item level.

This is what i have currently in my fact table:

```
Invoice Type        Item            Dollars
11111   Shipment    pancake         50
11111   Shipment    waffle          200
11111   Discount    discount item   20
11111   Discount    discount item   30
```

This is what i am looking to create:

```
item    dollars discount %  adjusted dollars
pancake 50      0.2         40
waffle  200     0.2         160
```

Here are the steps i am trying to achieve:

1. Add up the dollars for each Type

   - Shipment = 250
   - Discount = 50
2. Find the discount %

   - Discount / Shipment = 20%
3. Use that discount % to adjust the dollar amount for each item.

   - adjusted pancake = 50 * (1 - 0.2) = 40
   - adjusted waffle = 200 * (1 - 0.2) = 160
4. Add up those adjusted dollars in a measure.

The idea being that i could then put either items or invoices on columns in a pivot table and get the measure to give me an adjusted dollar amount.  I was able to do it for just invoices, but i cannot figure out how to do it at the item level.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following measures

**Shipment Amount:**

```
Shipment Amount = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( FactTable[Dollars] ),
        FactTable[Type] = "Shipment"
    )
```

**Invoice Discount %:**

```
Invoice Discount % = 
VAR InvoiceShipment = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( FactTable[Dollars] ),
        FILTER ( 
            ALLEXCEPT ( FactTable, FactTable[Invoice] ), 
            FactTable[Type] = "Shipment"
        )
    )
VAR InvoiceDiscount = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( FactTable[Dollars] ),
        FILTER ( 
            ALLEXCEPT ( FactTable, FactTable[Invoice] ), 
            FactTable[Type] = "Discount"
        )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE ( 
        InvoiceDiscount, 
        InvoiceShipment, 
        BLANK()
    )
```

**Adjusted Amount:**

```
Adjusted Amount = 
    SUMX ( 
        FactTable,
        [Shipment Amount] * ( 1 - [Invoice Discount %] )
    )
```

Now you can use these in your visualisation, as required.

[image]

See https://pwrbi.com/so_55602327/ for example PBIX file